# Change content of custom listView Android onclick?

Tags: android, listview

I have custom listview where I am previewing the data i fetched from server.
Now i want to change the data in the listview on its itemclick. The new data i want to preview also comes from the server.
This is my BaseAdapter class

```
    class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     Vector<String> data_text;
      int[] data_image;

   MyCustomAdapter()
   {
          data_text = null;
          data_image = null;
   }

   MyCustomAdapter(Vector<String> text, int[] image)
   {
          data_text = text;
          data_image = image;
   }

  public int getCount()
  {
         return data_text.size();
  }

 public String getItem(int position)
 {
         return null;
 }

 public long getItemId(int position)
 {
         return position;
 }

 public void updateResults( Vector<String> results) {
        data_text= results;
        //Triggers the list update
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {

          LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
          View row;

          row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list_element, parent, false);

          TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
          ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

          textview.setText(data_text.get(position).toString());
          imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

          return (row);
  }}
```

Please provide a solution.

Please note i want to preview data on the same activity on the onclick of listview.

And this is my onclick
l1 is the listview

```
    l1.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(appCat, image));

l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


    @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position,long id) 
        {
            View curr = parent.getChildAt((int) id);
            TextView c = (TextView)curr.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            String sel_item = c.getText().toString();
            API_GOD(URL);


             }});
```

API_GOD(URL) is the server side data which is recieve.
Now tell me how to update the list.

Comment: post code for API_GOD(URL); method.. you need to call notifydatasetchanged() after finishing API_GOD(URL);

Answer (score 0):

Write in side the getView()

```
textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                updateResults(results);

        });
```

Or do your work inside the OnClick

Answer (score 0):

You only have to set this adapter to your view `mCustomList.setAdapter(mMyCustomAdapter)` and then the click listener: `mCustomList.setOnItemClickListener(this);` you can implement the whole onclick inside the arguments or make your class implement the click listener `implements OnItemClickListener` The advantage of onItemClickListener is that you will get a position:
`@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos, long arg3) { }` So you are able to update just that item in the list and then notify your adapter.

```
@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position,long id) 
    {

        TextView c = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        String sel_item = c.getText().toString();
        API_GOD(URL);


         }});
```

Comment: I have added my onclicklistener code... Please tell me what do further. I did not understood what u said.

Comment: add onItemClickListener (not onClick) so you can get the position, then update your array/list and notifyDataChanged() in your adapter.

Comment: Sorry I meant onItemClickListener()...i have posted the code above in the question....please tell me what i am doing wrong....

Comment: changed the answer, you have to refer to the clicked item using "view"; then you could `c.setText("whatever");`